# in what stored procedure recieves multi-value parameter from ssrs?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

So i have stored procedure and ssrs report.
Ssrs report takes multi-value parameter and sends it to stored procedure.
Stored procedure expects that parameter as varchar(50) type (max length is around 15 characters).
If i select 1 value in report (thus not using multi-select property) it is working, but when i select more than 1 value it reports : `procedure or function ... has to many arguments specified.`

**In what format does SSMS stored procedure receives multi-value parameter? Is it a string like 'a,b,c'? a table?**

**And how can i check things like this by my self in future (this data flow and how data is sent and received)?**

Answer (score 2):

SSRS passes multi-values parameters to a stored procedure as a delimited `(n)varchar`. This means that you need to split the value after you have received it.

For modern versions of SQL Server, you would just use `STRING_SPLIT`:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.YourProc @SomeInt int, @MultiVal varchar(8000) AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@MultiVal,',') SS ON YT.SomeCol = SS.[Value]
    WHERE YTIntCol = @SomeInt;

END;
```

For older versions, you'll need to use a different splitter, such as a inline table-value function, CLR Function, or XML Splitter. There are 100's of examples of these on Stack Overflow.

Comment: So it is sent as (n)varchar. Ok. My situacion is a little more complex tho. I am getting data from another postgres database via ODBC driver and it is done with OPENQUERY. It is also made as stored procedure because im doing OPENQUERY with dynamic parameters. What i cant understand is that when i test it in ssms, i can pass string like 'a,b,c' or 'a' and it works but when i select multi-value with ssrs i get error.

Comment: *"when i select multi-value with ssrs i get error."* if you're getting errors, ***why*** is that information omitted in your question..? If you're using `OPENQUERY`, again, why are you not detailing that? Don't drip feed the infiormation.

Comment: You answered my first question and i thank you for that. Can you answer my second question? How can i see whats going on under the hood in this data trade between ssrs and stored procedure?

Comment: What do you mean "data trade" and "under the hood"? SSRS executes a stored proecedure, and SQL Server passes a dataset back. No different to if you were to execute a stored procedure in SSMS.

Comment: Well how did you know this: SSRS passes multi-values parameters to a stored procedure as a delimited (n)varchar.?

Comment: I honestly can't remember how I found out, @Sipjo7171 , I started using SSRS at least a decade ago. How use them is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-multi-value-parameter-to-a-report?view=sql-server-ver15) though; however, it is poor form that Microsoft link to an off-site resource to do this. I'll probably look at making a pull request on that later.

Comment: i figured this out. So for some reason SSRS do not work as i expected it when it uses stored procedure that have EXEC (@SOME_QUERY_IN_STRING). So i had to store the result of  EXEC (@SOME_QUERY_IN_STRING) in TEMP table and SELECT * from it. Now it works and passed multi-value parameter is applied properly. I im still definitely interested in this documentation you mentioned tho.

Comment: If you have `EXEC (@SOME_QUERY_IN_STRING)` I wouldn't be surprised if have a major security flaw there. You *really* should have posted your query in the question.

Comment: what do you mean security flaw? You mean if someone put QUERY inside parameter? If yes, how to prevent this? I can check for key words inside that parameter before doing EXEC. I still have not found a way to avoid @ SOME_QUERY_IN_STRING when using OPENQUERY and dynamic parameters.

Comment: You shouldn't let someone be writing a query in there at all, @Sipjo7171 .You should be having them only pass dynamic object names and **safely** inject them with `QUOTENAME`. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)